# При установке программы OpenProj получаю ошибку доступа к JRE

Tags: установка, openproj

Для создания проекта пытаюсь установить программу OpenProj, однако получаю ошибку:

> Не удалось загрузить библиотеку виртуальной машины Java: c:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8\bin\server\jvm.dll (ошибка = 193)

В оригинале звучит  как *Failed to load Java VM library: c:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8\bin\server\jvm.dll (errno = 193)*

У меня Windows 10 и стоит jre-1.8 и jdk-13.0.2

Путь, указанный в ошибке, ведет к нужному файлу в компьютере. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с ошибкой и нашел путь решения задачи